# Can you factorial a power?

Tags: problem-solving

I know this may be a straight forward question, but I looked around on google for about 20 minutes to find nothing. I am currently a year 8 student and came across a problem where I have to find the highest number using the four following numbers: $9, 5, -8$ and $-2$. I could use any mathematical I wanted to use, so I just used factorials. I came up with $(9! \times 5!)\times(-8x-2)!$, then, I came up with $5!^{9!}$ and then $9!^{(-8 \times-2)!}$. It may come up in a test and I didn't demonstrate this in class. Does this equation work and is there a higher number I could get with mathematical notation I don't know about? (Note - I can't use infinity.)
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using factorials, why stop at just one? E.g., $(5!)!$?

Comment: I was thinking about that. I just didn't want to make it over excessive and keep it clean :). It's not based around the highest number I don't think, I think it's based around creativity. But I will try it, thanks!

Comment: You can factorial a natural number and can then raise the result to a power as you have done. Example: $(3!)^2= 6^2=36$.

Comment: I see. My guess is that your teacher would want the mathematical symbols restricted to $+,-,\times,\div$ otherwise you have a never-ending sequence of steps as I mentioned above. You would still be allowed to use exponents as it doesn't introduce any new notation (just how I imagine the problem, though... I might very well be wrong).

Comment: Thanks! Does a factorial of multiple powers work too? As shown in the second equation I made?

Comment: Certainly, you can raise one factorial to another; they are numbers after all.

Comment: @Clayton , Its about demonstrating your knowledge of mathematical notation and coming up with the best idea. My first equation (9! x 5!)x(-8x-2)! was the best answer in the class because other members of the class only used +,−,×,÷.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner They did not specifty, I think they just assumed everyone was going to use basic arithmetic and did not know about other approaches.

Comment: I withdrew my earlier remark as precipitous.  If you're going to "step up" to exponentiation, though, I think  $$ 5!^{8!^{[(-2) \cdot (-9)]!}} \ $$ is even bigger...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Thats exactly what I tried to write man :).

Comment: As many of the responders show, this is a puzzle-game where some definite "boundaries" on permissible operations need to be set.

Comment: With the change you made, you can't change its whole number value, as you've done to 9 in (−2)⋅(−9)]!.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner As I mentioned in previous comments, I don't think they expected anyone to go beyond basic arithmetic.

Comment: Oops, I forgot where the minus sign was "attached": so $$5!^{9!^{[(-2) \cdot \ (-8)]!}} \ \ , $$ which I wrote before carelessly "rethinking" it.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Its all good man, thanks heaps, that's what I'll write in an exam if I need to use it again!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can include factorial in the exponent. but simpler would be $9!!!!!!! $ or $9^9^9^9^9^9^9$ or even further forms to make numbers bigger see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation

Comment: Thanks! This would work but if you do 9^9^9^9^9^9^9 you're just using the same number over and over again, which you can't really do, you can only use one of each number :)

Comment: ah I didn't see that part try 9 uparrow uparrow uparrow uparrow uparrow  5. it's far larger then anything computable. i.e. even if we wrote a single digit on every atom in the universe we wouldn't have written down the number.

Comment: probably can't even say for sure how many digits there are even though it's a finite number

Comment: Thanks man, I think that might be a more simple way of writing it.

Comment: (-8)! is a weird thing that could debatebly be larger but then it would be infinite rather it's any of a specific infinite set of natural numbers